# Why don't I have to deference a handle to an array to access an element within it?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, handle, dereference

Given some simple code like this:

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

List<String^>^ l = gcnew List<String^>;
l->Add("test1");
```

A member of my team was de-referencing every managed handle like this:

```
Console::WriteLine((*l)[0]);
```

Whereas I'd previously been doing this:

```
Console::WriteLine(l[0]);
```

He asked why you don't need to dereference to which the only answer that sprung to mind was "because of C++-CLI magic I'd not ever questioned before".

So why *does* that work?

Comment: You are using the indexer of the List class.  Friendly syntax, no special magic is required, `name[]` is good enough to use the indexer.  Causes a bit of a documentation problem since the indexer has no name, listed as `Item` in the MSDN docs.  That `(*name)[]` actually compiles is not exactly a feature, never once seen anybody do that.  Which as far as I can tell is the real question.  It just does, shrug.